# contender alterando-se e alterando tamanho de img

Tags: css, css3

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body > section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

section#categorias > div.internas > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

section#categorias > div.internas > div > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 28%;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #CCC;
}
section#categorias > div.internas > div > div > img {
    width: 60%;
}

section#categorias > div.internas > div > div > h3 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
}

section#categorias > div.internas > div > div > a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 0px) {

  div.internas {
      width: 100%;
  }
  
  section#categorias > div.internas > div > div, 
  section#duvidas > div.internas > div > article {
    width: 100% !important;
  }  
  
}
```

```html
<section id='categorias'>

  <div class="internas">
  
    <div>
 
      <div>

      <img src="https://ctemcasb.com.br/img/categorias/pecas.png" />

      <h3>Fornecedores de Peças</h3>

      <a href="fornecedores/6">Acesse aqui</a>

   </div>
   
    </div>
   
  </div>
 
</section>
```

Olá pessoal, estou precisando de um help.

Tenho o código acima. Tentei criar, conforme orientação do fórum, um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.

**O PROBLEMA:**

Funciona bem nos browser de PC e Notebook's.

Mas nos **browsers** de **celular**, a **imagem** não está obedecendo sua **altura** e ás vezes, é **div** principal.

Rodando o exemplo aqui mesmo no Stacks já dá para ter ima noção do erro!

Mas no celular é que o erro é mais grotesco.

na verdade, existem mais **blocos** do tipo:

```
  <div>

     <img src="https://ctemcasb.com.br/img/categorias/pecas.png" />

     <h3>Fornecedores de Peças</h3>

     <a href="fornecedores/6">Acesse aqui</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Dentro de

```
<section id='categorias'>

  <div class="internas">

    <div>

        ...

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

**Essa falha só dá para ser verificada em celulares.**

Em alguma **divs**, a **imagem** fica *alterada*, em outras é a **div** principal quem fica!

Eu não consegui entender!

**Em tempo:**

No **Internet Explorer 11**, tanto nos **PCs** quanto em **Notebooks** o erro ocorre igual!

Quem quiser dar uma olhada no seu próprio celular o link é ctemcasb.com.br.

No meio da página existem as categorias.

**Obs.: Não adianta reduzir o tamanho dos navegadores (com exceção do IE 11) nos computadores que o erro não acontece. Apenas em celulares.** Daí minha dificuldade!

**Print do IE 11 mais à esquerda**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca um print com uma imagem de como fica na tela de celulares. Outra coisa IE11 morreu esquece ele

Comment: kkk, a solução do colega resolveu. havia me esquecido de colocar o coração das media-query. Mas agora preciso mesmo resolver o problema para o IE 11. Adicionada print no final da pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deixe o width da imagem em 100% e o height em auto, para não deformar a imagem
veja também se está com o viewport no header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: opa, de fato, eu havia me esquecido de colocar de colocar a <meta name="viewport"... e resolveu o problema para os dispositivos  mobile que era o foco da pergunta. Então estou aceitando como a resposta. Mas não resolveu a questão do IE 11. Conhece algum hack que resolva? Mas desde já obrigado!

Comment: Bom, não entendi o porque. Mas colocando flex : 1; na imagem resolveu no IE 11.
Alguém pode me explicar?